# Libgdx , Mesh deforms when camera moves

Tags: java, camera, libgdx, mesh

i'm drawing a simple Mesh and it shows fine but when the camera moves, right or left, it deforms and doesn't move like a sprite would.

how it looks without moving the camera [link http://aetos.it.teithe.gr/~sskourti/temp/pic1.png](http://aetos.it.teithe.gr/~sskourti/temp/pic1.png)

how it looks moving it [link http://aetos.it.teithe.gr/~sskourti/temp/pic2.png](http://aetos.it.teithe.gr/~sskourti/temp/pic2.png)

desired effect when the camera is moving [link http://aetos.it.teithe.gr/~sskourti/temp/pic3.png](http://aetos.it.teithe.gr/~sskourti/temp/pic3.png)

What am i missing?

```
TestMesh mesh;
PerspectiveCamera camera;
ShaderProgram shader;

public TestScreen(){

    mesh = new TestMesh();

    camera = new PerspectiveCamera(67f, 2f*((float)Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/Gdx.graphics.getHeight()),2f);
    camera.position.set(0f, 0f, 1.5f);
    shader = new ShaderProgram(Gdx.files.internal("shaders/vertex.vsgl"), Gdx.files.internal("shaders/fragment.fsgl"));
}

public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.update();


    shader.begin();
    shader.setUniformMatrix("u_projectionViewMatrix", camera.combined);
    mesh.render(shader);
    shader.end();

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT)){
        camera.position.set(camera.position.x-1f, camera.position.y, camera.position.z);
    }else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT)){
        camera.position.set(camera.position.x+1f, camera.position.y, camera.position.z);
    }

}
```

TestMesh class , it extends MeshGameObject

```
public TestMesh(){
    addVertex(-0.5f, 0.5f,-2f);
    addVertex( 0.5f, 0.5f,-2f);
    addVertex( 0.5f,-0.5f,-2f);
    addVertex(-0.5f,-0.5f,-2f);


    addIndices(new short[] {0,1,2,3,0});
    create();
}
```

MeshGameObject

```
private Mesh mesh;
private float vertices[];
private Array<Float> v;
private short indeces[];

public MeshGameObject(){
    v = new Array<Float>();
}

public void create(){
    vertices = new float[v.size];
    for(int i=0;i<vertices.length;i++){
        vertices[i] = v.get(i).floatValue();
    }

    mesh = new Mesh(true, vertices.length/7, indeces.length, new VertexAttribute(Usage.Position,3,"a_position"), VertexAttribute.  ColorUnpacked());

    mesh.setVertices(vertices);
    mesh.setIndices(indeces);
}

public void render(ShaderProgram shader){
    mesh.render(shader,GL20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,indeces.length);
}

protected void addVertex(float x,float y,float z){
    v.add(new Float(x));    //x
    v.add(new Float(y));    //y
    v.add(new Float(z));    //z
    v.add(new Float(0));    //r
    v.add(new Float(0));    //g
    v.add(new Float(0));    //b
    v.add(new Float(1));    //a
}

protected void addIndices(short[] indeces){
    this.indeces = indeces;
}
```

Vertex Shader

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec4 a_color;

uniform mat4 u_projectionViewMatrix;

varying vec4 v_color;

void main()
{
v_color = a_color;
    gl_Position = a_position * u_projectionViewMatrix;
}
```

Fragment Shader

```
varying vec4 v_color;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = v_color;
}
```

Comment: it's definitely something to do with the perspective transform, is it supposed to be 2d or 3d? If 2d, you might want ortographic transform instead. If not, well, it's something to do with the perspective transform.

Comment: its supposed to be 2d. I have tried both Orthographic and Perspective cameras and i got the same result.

Comment: Completely random guess because I'm not sure, is the shader program matrix multiplication in the right order?

Comment: Thank you!!! i was doing 
gl_Position = a_position * u_projectionViewMatrix;
instead of gl_Position = u_projectionViewMatrix*a_position;
it works fine now